# Allow IPs with TCP Listener using RBAC (Envoy)

Tags: postgresql, tcp, rbac, envoyproxy

I am trying to achieve the following with Envoy:

- Allow TCP traffic to a Postgres service with RBAC rules to allow only a few IPs.

This is my listener setup.

```yaml
    - name: listener_postgres
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 54322
      filter_chains:
        filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.rbac
            config:
              stat_prefix: rbac_postgres
              rules:
                action: ALLOW
                policies:
                  "allow":
                    permissions:
                      - any: true
                    principals:
                      - source_ip:
                          address_prefix: XX.XX.XX.XX
                          prefix_len: 32
                      - source_ip:
                          address_prefix: XX.XX.XX.XX
                          prefix_len: 32
                      - source_ip:
                          address_prefix: XX.XX.XX.XX
                          prefix_len: 32
          - name: envoy.tcp_proxy
            config:
              stat_prefix: tcp_postgres
              cluster: database_service
```

I can confirm that the service is setup correctly because I can remove the RBAC rules and I can connect successfully.

When the RBAC rules are added I can not connect to the Postgres database.

But for some reason nothing seems to work, I have also tried remote_ip and direct_remote_ip in place of source_ip.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that setting the attribute to '**remote_ip**' as suggested by **Rahul Pratap** worked.

Here is a **working example**:

```yaml
    - name: listener_postgres
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 54322
      filter_chains:
        filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.rbac
            config:
              stat_prefix: rbac_postgres
              rules:
                action: ALLOW
                policies:
                  "allow":
                    permissions:
                      - any: true
                    principals:
                      - remote_ip:
                          address_prefix: XX.XX.XX.XX
                          prefix_len: 32
          - name: envoy.tcp_proxy
            config:
              stat_prefix: tcp_postgres
              cluster: database_service
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I ran into the same issue and this is the configuration worked for me.
I used `remote_ip` attribute.
Also, check the updated filters names

```
- name: listener_postgres
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 54322
      filter_chains:
        filters:
          - name: envoy_rbac
            config:
              stat_prefix: rbac_postgres
              rules:
                action: ALLOW
                policies:
                  "allow":
                    permissions:
                      - any: true
                    principals:
                      - remote_ip:
                          address_prefix: XX.XX.XX.XX
                          prefix_len: 32
          - name: envoy_tcp_proxy
            config:
              stat_prefix: tcp_postgres
              cluster: database_service
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your suggestion, however, when I changed the filter name to 'envoy_rbac' I received the following error:

Didn't find a registered implementation for name: 'envoy_rbac'

Comment: @BenOsborne the config rahul left may have been from a different envoy version, which would explain the different name for the filter.  Can't tell which of you is outdated without looking into the API, but one of you will need to update at some point.